# Subdivide an expression into alternative subpattern - using gsub()

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to subdivide my metacharacter expression in my `gsub()` function. But it does not return anything found.

Task: I want to delete all sections of string that contain either `.ST` or `-XST` in my vector of strings.

As you can see below, using one expression works fine. But the `|` expression simply does not work. I'm following the metacharacter guide on https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/ItDT/HTML/node84.html

What can be the issue? And what caused this issue?

My data

```
> rownames(table.summary)[1:10]
 [1] "AAK.ST"      "ABB.ST"      "ALFA.ST"     "ALIV-SDB.ST" "AOI.ST"      "ATCO-A.ST"   "ATCO-B.ST"   "AXFO.ST"     "AXIS.ST"     "AZN.ST"

> gsub(pattern = '[.](.*)$ |  [-](.*)$', replacement = "", x = rownames(table.summary)[1:10])
 [1] "AAK.ST"      "ABB.ST"      "ALFA.ST"     "ALIV-SDB.ST" "AOI.ST"      "ATCO-A.ST"   "ATCO-B.ST"   "AXFO.ST"     "AXIS.ST"     "AZN.ST"       

> gsub(pattern = '[.](.*)$', replacement = "", x = rownames(table.summary)[1:10])
 [1] "AAK"      "ABB"      "ALFA"     "ALIV-SDB" "AOI"      "ATCO-A"   "ATCO-B"   "AXFO"     "AXIS"     "AZN"     

> gsub(pattern = '[-](.*)$', replacement = "", x = rownames(table.summary)[1:10])
 [1] "AAK.ST"  "ABB.ST"  "ALFA.ST" "ALIV"    "AOI.ST"  "ATCO"    "ATCO"    "AXFO.ST" "AXIS.ST" "AZN.ST"
```

Comment: Remove the whitespace, try `'[.].*$|-.*$'` (or even `'[.-].*$'`).

Comment: Please make your examples reproducible and minimal.  `table.summary` is not relevant here so it should be simplified to `x <- ...; gsub(..., x)` . Use `dput(x)` to show `x` reproducibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you tested your regex with a flag like `IgnorePatternWhitespace` (`VERBOSE`, `/x`) that allows whitespace inside patterns for readability. You [can use it](http://ideone.com/aaBCYt) with `perl=T` option:

```
d <- c("AAK.ST","ABB.ST","ALFA.ST","ALIV-SDB.ST","AOI.ST","ATCO-A.ST","ATCO-B.ST","AXFO.ST", "AXIS.ST","AZN.ST")
gsub('(?x)[.](.*)$ |  [-](.*)$', '', d, perl=T)
## [1] "AAK"  "ABB"  "ALFA" "ALIV" "AOI"  "ATCO" "ATCO" "AXFO" "AXIS" "AZN"
```

However, you really do not have to use that complex regex here.

If you plan to remove all substrings from ther first hyphen or dot up to the end, you may use the following regex:

```
[.-].*$
```

The character class `[.-]` will match the first `.` or `-` symbol and `.*` wil match all characters up to the end of the string (`$`).

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/UC2GGZ):

```
d <- c("AAK.ST","ABB.ST","ALFA.ST","ALIV-SDB.ST","AOI.ST","ATCO-A.ST","ATCO-B.ST","AXFO.ST", "AXIS.ST","AZN.ST")
gsub("[.-].*$", "", d)
```

Result: `[1] "AAK"  "ABB"  "ALFA" "ALIV" "AOI"  "ATCO" "ATCO" "AXFO" "AXIS" "AZN"`

Answer (score 1):

This will find `.ST` or `-XST` at the end of the text and substitute it with empty characters string (effectively removing that part). Don't forget that `gsub` **returns** modified string, not modifies it in place. You won't see any change until you reassign return value back to some variable.

```
strings <- c("AAK.ST", "ABB.ST", "ALFA.ST", "ALIV-SDB.ST", "AOI.ST", "ATCO-A.ST", "ATCO-B.ST", "AXFO.ST", "AXIS.ST", "AZN.ST", "AAC-XST", "AAD-XSTV")

strings <- gsub('(\\.ST|-XST)$', '', strings)
```

Your regular expression (`[.](.*)$ |  [-](.*)$'`), if not for unnecessary spaces, would **remove everything** from first dot (`.`) or dash (`-`) to end of text. This might be what you want, but not what you said you want.